# Recorrer un obj que viene de una API y agregarle a cada clave un nuevo valor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Buenas tardes comunidad,

estoy con un proyecto personal y me encuentro confundido o quiza quemado y no veo la solucion...

Resulta que consumo una API con JS, donde tiene varios nudos ej:

```
pricipal: {
 0:persona: {
     name: 'Jose',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211}
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
     }
   }
 1:persona: {
     name: 'Pepe',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211}
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
      3:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
      4:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
     }
   }
}
```

y necesito agregarle dentro de cupon un ID por cada cupon osea me tendrria que queda asi,

```
pricipal: {
 0:persona: {
     name: 'Jose',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211, id: 'dasjokh1' }
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151, id: '213312ds'}
     }
   }
 1:persona: {
     name: 'Pepe',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211, id: 'dsad1d21ed'}
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151, id: '12333124'}
      3:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151, id: 'dsa'}
      4:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151, id: 'dasdasdas'}
     }
   }
}
```

pero no logro llegar al cupon, recorri el obj, utilice el spreak operator, etc... pero no logro insertar ese id por cada cupon!!!, (esos numeritos detras del obj me los tira el navegador 0: 1:,etc...) y la idea es que no mute el obj

GRacias!

Comment: Y como vendría a ser la lógica de esos `id`? son alfanuméricos aleatorios? vienen de algún array? los quieres llenar manualmente?...

Comment: sisi esos ID ya tengo preparada una funcion donde los hace como tipo hash pero ese no es el problema, el problema es que no puedo llegar a colocar dentro de cada cupon una nueva clave llamada en este caso ID

Comment: ok, entiendo...

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa, sería usar la instrucción [**`for...in`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) para iterar sobre las propiedades de tu objeto.

Pongamos un ejemplo con tu objeto para analizar qué es lo que devuelve:

```js
let principal = {
 0:{
   persona: {
     name: 'Jose',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211},
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
     }
   }
 },
 1:{
   persona: {
     name: 'Pepe',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211},
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151},
      3:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151},
      4:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
     }
   }
 }
}

for (let key in principal) {
  console.log("clave ->", key)
  console.log("valor ->", principal[key])
}
```

Con `key`, estamos accediendo a las claves (que son `0` y `1`), y con `principal[key]` estamos accediendo a los valores de esas dos claves (por eso que el `key` está entre corchetes).

Hasta aquí, ya ingresamos a los valores, que son también objetos. Estos objetos, tiene una clave llamado `persona`, y dentro de esta, otra clave llamada `cupon` (que el objetivo es ingresar ahí para posteriormente ingresar a todos sus elementos y agregar el `id`). Entonces, hasta ahí podemos ingresar de la siguiente forma:

```js
let principal = {
 0:{
   persona: {
     name: 'Jose',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211},
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
     }
   }
 },
 1:{
   persona: {
     name: 'Pepe',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211},
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151},
      3:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151},
      4:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
     }
   }
 }
}

for (let key in principal) {
  console.log(principal[key].persona.cupon);
}
```

Y observamos que ya nos devolvió a todos elementos de `cupon`, y aquí es donde queremos agregar los `id` a cada uno de ellos. Fácilmente, podrías recorrerlo nuevamente con la misma instrucción, almacenando en una variable a `principal[key].persona.cupon` y luego usarlo como los valores que queremos recorrer, y a cada uno de ellos, agregarles el valor `id`, quedando así:

```js
let principal = {
 0:{
   persona: {
     name: 'Jose',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211},
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
     }
   }
 },
 1:{
   persona: {
     name: 'Pepe',
     cupon: {
      0:{entrada: 'prueba 1', code: 3211},
      1:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151},
      3:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151},
      4:{entrada: 'prueba 2', code: 2151}
     }
   }
 }
}

for (let key in principal) {
  // "cuponObj" son los elementos (objetos) de "cupon".
  let cuponObj = principal[key].persona.cupon;
  for (let cuponKey in cuponObj) {
    // ingreso a los valores (que es "cuponObj") de las claves de esos elementos y le agrego el "id" a cada uno de ellos.
    cuponObj[cuponKey].id = "123123";
  }
}

console.log(principal)
```